# How to reset <small> tag in CSS

Tags: css

I would also like to reset the font-size of `<small>` tag too normal HTML elements.

Like I want the content in small tag to be 13px of what other tags are.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way is to do

```
small {
   font-size:inherit;
}
```

This way, the small tag will be the same size as whatever element it's contained in, so if for some reason you have:

```
<h1>This is some <small>small</small> text</h1>
```

The word "small" would be the same size as its surrounding words.

The one caveat with this is that I'm not sure if it will work in IE. I suspect that it will, but you'd have to try it to be sure.

You might want to look into using a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) that takes care of this and similar issues for all tags.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question - although to be fair to you, the question is far from clear!

Comment: Actually, in retrospect I think you may have hit on what he is asking. I'm upvoting in case this is a correct interpretation of a very confusingly worded question.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's hard to tell what you're asking. Here's how to set the font-size of those tags to 13px.

```
small {
  font-size: 13px; /* you can use !important, but I wouldn't recommend it */
}
```

Second, 13px is not a very small size, unless the rest of your text is enormous. That fact, together with your phrasing ("I want the content in small tag to be 13px of what other tags are") leads me to suspect that what you really mean is you want the <small> text to be a percentage of the rest of the text. You can do this as follows:

```
small {
  font-size: 13%;
}
```

However, this seems rather small. If you really want a percentage, I'd suggest something between 60% and 80%.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it 13px exactly, Keltex's answer will do it for you.

If you want to reduce the size by 13 pixels from the base `font-size` of its parent, you have the following options as there is no "make it exactly 13 pixels less" operator available:

1. If you know the base `font-size`, hardcode a value that is your 13 pixels less in your selector.
2. Rely on **percentages** or **ems** to size it down appropriately. For instance, instead of "13 pixels less" think of it as being a given percentage of the base font-size. i.e.

   p{ font-size: 24px; }

   small{ font-size: 45% /* Will make it approximately 13 pixels smaller */ }

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand. Do you want to make text in `small` tags the same size as the rest of the text? I'll assume that.

```
small {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

This will make the `small` tag have the same font-size as the rest of the text.
Why you would want such a thing is beyond my comprehension, but you have your answer.

**[edit]** this has the same effect as @notJim's answer - if the parent's font-size changes, this one adapts accordingly and adopts that new size.

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
small
{
    font-size: 13px !important;
}
```

Comment: @Jez !important denotes that this rule supersedes later rules, which ensures in this case that ALL small tags will be 13px no matter if a later rule in the stylesheet says otherwise (for example "a small {...}") - I'm not sure it is relevant in this answer, it's really answering an anticipated next question.

Comment: I encourage people to use the **!important** directive only as a last resort, and even then to find a way around it if possible.

Comment: i tried this code already before asking this question.. doesnt seem to be working dont know why